# OpenCV program not connecting to webcam/Camera

Tags: c, opencv, video, camera

i am trying to learn about OpenCV and found a really good tutorial on youtube however, everytime i am told to "select a video device" on Visual Studio, a R6010 error pops up and i have to keep aborting the program. Here is the source code. I am using OpenCV 2.2, 2010 Visua Studio and the camera in question is a HP TrueVision HD. Thanks!

```
//tracker1

#include<opencv\cvaux.h>
#include<opencv\highgui.h>
#include<opencv\cxcore.h>

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* []){

    CvSize size640x480 = cvSize(640, 480);

    CvCapture* p_capWebCam; //assign a webcam (later)

    IplImage* p_imgOriginal; //image given by the webcam
    IplImage* p_imgProcessed; //webcam image processed

    CvMemStorage* p_strStorage; //passing stored variables

    CvSeq* p_seqCircles;

    float* p_fltXYRadius; //3 points, 0 = X, 1 = Y, 2 = Radius

    int i; //looping integer

    char charCheckForEscKey;

    p_capWebCam = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);

    if(p_capWebCam == NULL){
        printf("error, webcam not found");
        getchar();
        return(-1);
    }

    cvNamedWindow("original", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvNamedWindow("processed", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    p_imgProcessed = cvCreateImage(size640x480, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

    while(1){
        p_imgOriginal = cvQueryFrame(p_capWebCam); //get frame of webcame
        if(p_capWebCam == NULL){ //when the frame is not attained
            printf("error, no frames were attained");
            getchar();
            break;
        }

        cvInRangeS(p_imgOriginal, CV_RGB(175,0,0), CV_RGB(256, 100, 100), p_imgProcessed);

        p_strStorage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

        cvSmooth(p_imgProcessed, p_imgProcessed, CV_GAUSSIAN, 9 ,9);

        p_seqCircles = cvHoughCircles(p_imgProcessed, p_strStorage, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, p_imgProcessed->height/4, 100, 50, 10, 400);

        for(i=0; i<p_seqCircles->total; i++){
            p_fltXYRadius = (float*)cvGetSeqElem(p_seqCircles, i);
            printf("ball position x = %f, y = %f, r = %f \n", p_fltXYRadius[0], p_fltXYRadius[1], p_fltXYRadius[2]);

            cvCircle(p_imgOriginal, cvPoint(cvRound(p_fltXYRadius[0]), cvRound(p_fltXYRadius[1])), 3, CV_RGB(0, 255, 0), CV_FILLED);

            cvCircle(p_imgOriginal, cvPoint(cvRound(p_fltXYRadius[0]), cvRound(p_fltXYRadius[1])), cvRound(p_fltXYRadius[2]), CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), 3);
        }

        cvShowImage("original", p_imgOriginal);
        cvShowImage("processed", p_imgProcessed);

        cvReleaseMemStorage(&p_strStorage);

        charCheckForEscKey = cvWaitKey(10);
        if(charCheckForEscKey == 27) break;
    }

    cvReleaseCapture(&p_capWebCam);
    cvDestroyWindow("original");
    cvDestroyWindow("processed");


}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug it yourself? You can use log statements and corner the line of code which fails.

Comment: Hi, yeah i found out which line of code was the problem, it was " cvInRangeS(p_imgOriginal, CV_RGB(175,0,0), CV_RGB(256, 100, 100), p_imgProcessed);" line which was messing it all up! Thanks for your response, much appreciated!